# update array with new content in reducer redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am still getting my head around functional programming and how to return a non mutated object from a reducer.

I am trying to replace the contents of an old object in a reducer, without mutating the old state.

so if the old state was

```
 {
        Actors:"Michael Keaton, Jack Nicholson, Kim Basinger, Robert Wuhl"
        Awards:"Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 22 nominations."
        Country:"USA, UK"
        Director:"Tim Burton"
 }
```

and the new state is

```
{
        Actors:"George Clooney"
        Awards:"Won 9 Oscars."
        Country:"USA"
        Director:"Quentin Tarantino"
 }
```

My reducer looks like this

```
function reducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      return //new Array here that has not been mutatated
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

My payload looks like this

```
{
    Actors:"Michael Keaton, Jack Nicholson, Kim Basinger, Robert Wuhl"
    Awards:"Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 22 nominations."
    Country:"USA, UK"
    Director:"Tim Burton"
}
```

Comment: How is your `action.payload` looks like?

Comment: Your payload is the old state?

Comment: Where is the `array` here?

Answer (score 1):

If all the values of your object are changing everytime, you can simply return that new payload as new state. But if only some of the values are changing then You can use ES6 [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [object-assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign) as npm module.

If all the values are changing everytime then,

```
function reducer(state = {}, action){
   switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      return action.payload;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

If some of the values are changing then,

```
function reducer(state = {}, action){
   switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      // let say Actors field changed, then 
      return Object.assign({}, state, {Actors: "Michael Keaton, Jack Nicholson, Kim Basinger, Robert Wuhl" });
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use non-mutative functions and return the new data structure.

If your state is simply {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} and you want it to become {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6} just return {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}.

```
function reducer(state = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      return action.payload // assuming action.payload = {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

It gets more interesting when you want the new state = [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4, b:5, c: 6}].

For a good list of mutative vs non-mutative functions, this is helpful:
https://jeff.is/blog/mutative-vs-non-mutative-array-methods-in-js.html

I've also found React's immutability helpers nice for deeply nested structures.  They use a Mongo style syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about why you need array operators when you're dealing with an object. With this current state, you can do this one of two ways, depending on your build tools, polyfills, and/or target browsers.

Using `Object.assign()`

```
function reducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        Actors: action.Actors,
        Awards: action.Awards,
        Country: action.Country,
        Director: action.Director
      });
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Or with spread operator `...`

```
function reducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      return {
        ...state,
        Actors: action.Actors,
        Awards: action.Awards,
        Country: action.Country,
        Director: action.Director
      }
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you need only a part of the state object. Say actors is an object and you want to change only Actors.name. for example